# Request order verification with WireMock

Tags: java, wiremock

I have an API I'm supposed to PUT to several times, in a specific order. I'm testing my client using WireMock, and I'd like to check in my test that the requests were made in the proper order.

Since this API will return a 204 No Content, my code doesn't need the result of previous requests to make the next one, which seems me to rule out WireMock scenarios.

So, does WireMock have a feature similar to Mockito's `inOrder` ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through WireMock [Scenario](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/) feature, an example of this in the documentation:

> For example, suppose we’re writing a to-do list application consisting
>   of a rich client of some kind talking to a REST service. We want to
>   test that our UI can read the to-do list, add an item and refresh
>   itself, showing the updated list.

```
{
    "scenarioName": "To do list",
    "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/todo/items"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body" : "<items><item>Buy milk</item></items>"
    }
}

{
    "scenarioName": "To do list",
    "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
    "newScenarioState": "Cancel newspaper item added",
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/todo/items",
        "bodyPatterns": [
            { "contains": "Cancel newspaper subscription" }
         ]
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 201
    }
}

{
    "scenarioName": "To do list",
    "requiredScenarioState": "Cancel newspaper item added",
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/todo/items"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body" : "<items><item>Buy milk</item><item>Cancel newspaper subscription</item></items>"
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that... I have a scenario with 3 states: 1) get execution id, 2) upload attachment, 3) report run status. The order of requests is important. I am switching the order of verifications in my test just to see if it fails and it does not :( Anything else?